# Unexpected end of JSON input when JSON is valid

Tags: node.js, json, rest, express, https

I am using express to get data from a public API and use the data in my front end.

This is my characters route which works fine on certain Public API URLs, but most that I try  ends up in an unexpected end of input error.

I am also getting an
`Unexpected token , in JSON at position 48`. How can this happen when it appears to be valid JSON?

```
const express = require('express'); // Web Framework
const https = require('https');
const router = express.Router();

const api = 'https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/games?title=batman&steamAppID=35140&limit=60&exact=0';

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    https.get(api, (response) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        
        response.on('data', (d) => {
            try{
            const data = JSON.parse(d);
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })

        // res.send("Running")
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

This is my index.js which uses the character route

```
const express = require('express'); // Web Framework
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

const charactersRoute = require('./routes/characters');


//Characters Route
app.use('/characters', charactersRoute)

app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

This is the JSON I am trying to parse. I validated this is valid JSON on those JSON validation sites.

```
[
    {
        "gameID": "146",
        "steamAppID": "35140",
        "cheapest": "14.95",
        "cheapestDealID": "LNCZ5EicmEMiwyfYVw%2FNdGPos9V7MzoPId2UuwaBqvA%3D",
        "external": "Batman: Arkham Asylum Game of the Year Edition",
        "internalName": "BATMANARKHAMASYLUMGAMEOFTHEYEAREDITION",
        "thumb": "https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/35140/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1634156906"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`https` `response` is a stream that returns chunks of data in the `data` event, so you need to concatenate data there (store buffer raw data into an array), and parse it in the `.end` event, when the response is finished, and then you can use `res.json` to send it to the consumer:

try this:

```
const express = require('express'); // Web Framework
const https = require('https');
const router = express.Router();

const api = 'https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/games?title=batman&steamAppID=35140&limit=60&exact=0';

router.get("/", function(req, res) {

    https.get(api, (response) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        const resData = [];

        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            resData.push(chunk);
        });

        response.on('end', function() {

            try {
                const data = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(resData).toString());
                console.log(data);
                res.json(data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I will need to read a bit more about the https module